# Overloading conversion operator template

Tags: c++

Consider the following simple example

```
struct C
{
    template <typename T> operator T () {return 0.5;}
    operator int () {return 1;}
    operator bool () {return false;}
};

int main ()
{
    C c;
    double x = c;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled with Clang, it gives the following error

```
test.cpp:11:12: error: conversion from 'C' to 'double' is ambiguous
    double x = c;
           ^   ~
test.cpp:4:5: note: candidate function
    operator int () {return 1;}
    ^
test.cpp:5:5: note: candidate function
    operator bool () {return false;}
    ^
test.cpp:3:27: note: candidate function [with T = double]
    template <typename T> operator T () {return 0.5;}
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

Other compilers generate similar errors, e.g., GCC and Intel iclc

If I remove `operator int` and `operator bool`. It compiles fine and work as expected. If only remove one of them, that is keep the template operator and say `operator int`, then the non-template version is always chosen.

My understanding is that only when the template and non-template overloaded functions are equal in the sense that they are both perfect match or both require the same conversion sequence, the non-template version will be preferred. However in this case, it appears that the compiler does not see the operator template as a perfect match. And when both the `bool` and `int` overloading are present, then naturally it considers they are ambiguous.

In summary, my question is that why the operator template is not considered a perfect match in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is interesting.  There are two ways to read a critical part of section 13.3.3.  The original example should definitely call the function template, but the version where one of the non-templates is removed might be argued to be ambiguous.

13.3.3:

> A viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICS_i(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS_i(`F2`), and then
>
> - for some argument *j*, ICS_j(`F1`) is a better conversion sequence than ICS_j(`F2`), or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type, or, if not that,
> - `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
> - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.
>
> If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by overload resolution; otherwise the call is ill-formed.

In the example, clang correctly identifies the set of three viable candidate functions:

```
C::operator int()
C::operator bool()
C::operator double<double>()
```

The third is a function template specialization.  (I don't think the syntax above is legal, but you get the idea: at this point of overload resolution it's not treated as a template, but as a specialization with a definite function type.)

The only Implicit Conversion Sequence on arguments here (ICS1) is the exact match "lvalue `C`" to "`C&`" on the implicit parameter, so that won't make a difference.

This example is exactly the situation described in the second bullet, so the function returning `double` is clearly better than the other two.

Here's where it gets weird: By a very literal reading, `operator int` is also better than the template specialization, because of the third bullet.  "Wait a minute, shouldn't 'better than' be antisymmetric? How can you say `F1` is better than `F2` AND `F2` is better than `F1`?"  Unfortunately, the Standard doesn't explicitly say anything of the sort.  "Doesn't the second bullet take priority over the third bullet because of the 'if not that' phrase?"  Yes, for constant `F1` and `F2`.  But the Standard doesn't say that satisfying the second bullet for `(F1,F2)` makes the third bullet for `(F2,F1)` not applicable.

Of course, since `operator int` is not better than `operator bool` and vice versa, there is still "exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions".

I'm not exactly endorsing this weird reading, except maybe to report it as a Standard defect.  Going with that would have bizarre consequences (like *removing* an overload which was *not* the best from this example changes a program from well-formed to ambiguous!).  I think the intent is for the second bullet to be considered both ways before the third bullet is considered at all.

Which would mean the function template should be selected by overload resolution, and this is a clang bug.

Comment: Your "weird reading" of the standard is very interesting and actually make quite a lot sense to me. If I understand it correctly, whether operator int is better than the template depends on which is F1 and which is F2. If we consider F1 = op int, F2 = op<double>, then at bullet 3 we determine F1 is better than F2 and stop. But if we consider F1 = op<double>, F2 = op int, then at bullet 2 we determine F1 is better and stop. But if there are three of them, then op int and op bool are no longer better than others, and thus no ambiguous

Answer (score 11):

Let's break this down into two different problems:

**1. Why does this generate a compiler error?**

```
struct C
{
    operator bool () {return false;}
    operator int () {return 1;}
};
```

As both `int` and `bool` can be implicitly converted to `double`, the compiler can not know which function it should use. There are two functions which it could use and neither one takes precedence over the other one.

**2. Why isn't the templated version a perfect match?**

```
struct C
{
    template <typename T> operator T () {return 0.5;}
    operator int () {return 1;}
};
```

Why is `operator int()` called when requesting a double?

> The non-template function is called because a non-template function takes precedence in overload resolution. ([Overloading function templates](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/overloading_function_templates.htm))

**EDIT:**
I was wrong! As Yan Zhou mentioned in his comment, and as it is stated in the link I provided, a perfect match in the templated function takes precedence over the non-templated function.

I tested your code (compiled with g++ 4.7.2), and it worked as expected: it returned `0.5`, in other words, the templated function was used!

**EDIT2:**
I now tried with clang and I can reproduce the behaviour you described. As it works correctly in gcc, this seems to be a bug in clang.

Comment: The first part I already figured out as stated in the question. However the second part, non-template function only take precedence in overload resolution when other aspects are equal. In this case, the template does not require conversion, it returns a double while the non-template operator return int or bool and then need to be converted to double. So I still don't get why it is not a perfect match. Even in the link you give, the second call to `f` shows that a perfect match template take precedence. Non -template take precedence is the first and third call

Comment: @YanZhou you are right, I updated my answer. But my application seems having a different behaviour than yours. I tested it with gcc, and am currently installing clang for comparision.

Comment: What GCC version you used? I tried G++ 4.7 and it gives the same error as Clang, so does Intel icpc 13.1

Comment: My mistake, it was G++4.2 reproduce the problem while G++4.7 does complain nothing. But I do not think this is a bug of clang. Intel icpc 12.1 and 13.0 both produce the same error as clang as well as some other earlier gcc. Since only recent g++ accept this code, I can only assume that this is actually a problem with g++